# R gsub returns incorrect data

Tags: regex, r, vector, gsub

I am new to using `R` and I am having issues with using `gsub` to format my list properly. I am needing to make two replacements.

- First replacement replacing everything after `@` with `@mydomain.com`
- Second replacement replacing all `www.` with an empty value.

> Update

I am currently running `gsub` twice and corrected with my code it works. I had too many gsub instances that i didnt see.

```
vec <- c('john@mail.com', 'mike@mail.com', 'robbie.b@yahoo.com', 
         'zack.l.harris@aol.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.gmail.com', 
         'www.domain.com', 'www.example.com')

vec <- gsub("@.*\\.com", "@mydomain.com", vec)
vec <- gsub("www\\.", "", vec)

print(vec)
```

> Update

But I want to run `gsub` as **one instance** replacing both at the same time if possible still.

Comment: You didn't assign the result of the first `gsub` call to anything.

Comment: you can nest it:  `vec <- gsub("www\\.", "", gsub("@.*\\.com", "@example.com", vec))`.

Comment: Its assigned in my code

Comment: Please show us exactly what your problem is then; if it's assigned in your code, you shouldn't be getting incorrect format.  See my answer below which demonstrates.  If that's not what you're looking for, please show us the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've deleted my answer below.  Any particular reason why running it twice isn't satisfactory?  I imagine most users would find that both simpler and more readable than other solutions.

Comment: It's not possible with `gsub` in a single call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I've done this, you could cascade your `gsub` functions together.

```
vec <- gsub('@[^.]*\\.[^.]*', '@mydomain.com', gsub('www\\.', '', vec))
print(vec)
```

Another solution is to create vectors for your **`old values`** and **`replacement values`**

```
re  <- c('@[^.]*\\.[^.]*', 'www\\.')
val <- c('@mydomain.com',  '')

recurse <- function(pattern, repl, x) {
    for (i in 1:length(pattern))
       x <- gsub(pattern[i], repl[i], x)
       x
}

vec <- c('john@mail.com', 'mike@mail.com', 'robbie.b@yahoo.com', 
         'zack.l.harris@aol.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.gmail.com', 
         'www.domain.com', 'www.example.com')

print(recurse(re, val, vec))
```

Output

```
"john@mydomain.com"          "mike@mydomain.com"         
"robbie.b@mydomain.com"      "zack.l.harris@mydomain.com"
"google.com"                 "gmail.com"                 
"domain.com"                 "example.com"
```

Comment: I like the recurse function you made.